Why is my liquid simulation not showing?
I have applied the fluid in physics property but the liquid doesn't seem to be showing. Did I overlook something or is there something wrong with my model?




Several problems... first of all, the Effector object which you use for the glass and the Flow object which should become the liquid both have inverted normals as you can see showing in red when enabling the Face Orientation overlay (and you have to switch the objects back to show at least as Solid because the wireframe will not display the orientation):

To fix that, go into Edit Mode select all with A, then Shift+N to Recalculate Normals. Now they should show blue in the overlays.
The next thing is, the glass effector object is set to Is Planar. Disable that, because it is no planar object and it will give problems with simulating the fluid inside the glass.

The domain has a very low Resolution Divisions value with the default 32. To make the fluid distribute better inside the glass I would set it to at least 100.

Then - and this is the real problem for your animation - you are mixing Rigid Body with Fluid simulations - this does not work, they are not interacting with each other. You have made the Flow object a Rigid Body object as well - but this object is not the simulated fluid mesh afterwards. So the ice cubes will not "sink" into the fluid and just lie on top of it.
You cannot make the domain - which will generate the fluid mesh - a rigid body, because then the rigid body ice cubes are inside another rigid body - which will only lead to them being shot out immediately. Starting with the ice cubes above the domain will not work either, they will just land on top of it.
The only thing you can do is disabling Rigid Body on the Flow object while keeping the ice cubes rigid bodies and effectors - this will make them affect the fluid. Problem here is: they will fall to the bottom of the glass, not float and create a massive splash for falling fast through the liquid.
For the last part there is no real solution in Blender with just the simulations. The rigid bodies can affect the fluid being set to Effector, but the fluid does not affect the rigid bodies. So you only animate the ice cubes as if they were landing on water and then floating at the surface.

I see what you are talking about but anyway, I am grateful for your explanation too
